# Wifi Killer Wireless doesn't work P34G

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, madwifi

I cant make my wifi connection to work in xubuntu 14.04.
It cant even detect my wifi adapter.

More info:

- Laptop: Gigabyte P34G v5(skylake)
- Wifi: Killer Wireless
- OS: Xubuntu
- Kernel: 4.5

Any help would be great.

**`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`:**

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

**`dmesg | grep ath`** after installing the firmware:

```
[    1.906421] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.908195] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.153143] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:04:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.155968] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    2.155972] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    2.158712] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[    2.158714] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    2.159174] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
[    2.221246] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin failed with error -2
[    2.221482] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 ed5f849a
[    3.268382] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_hdmi cmac uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev hid_generic media usbhid btusb btrtl snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mxm_wmi sparse_keymap joydev snd_pcm intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal rfcomm intel_powerclamp bnep snd_seq_midi coretemp snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi kvm_intel snd_seq i915 kvm ath10k_pci irqbypass ath10k_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ath ghash_clmulni_intel drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device mac80211 drm aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper snd_timer cryptd snd rtsx_pci_ms input_leds i2c_algo_bit serio_raw soundcore memstick fb_sys_fops cfg80211 syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt mei_me mei shpchp hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel bluetooth i2c_hid wmi video pinctrl_sunrisepoint pinctrl_intel hid intel_lpss_acpi acpi_als intel_lpss kfifo_buf industrialio acpi_pad mac_hid nls_iso8859_1 parport_pc ppdev lp parport uas usb_storage rtsx_pci_sdmmc psmouse ahci r8169 rtsx_pci libahci mii fjes
[    3.268401]  [<ffffffff81080e72>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[    3.268402]  [<ffffffff81080f0c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[    4.340813] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    7.340669] ath10k_pci 0000:04:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[    7.408216] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    7.408218] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    7.408220] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    7.408220] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 updated my question . Thank you for reply.

Comment: @CaalSaalVI Please edit the question to add the recent `dmesg | grep ath10k; ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because custom kernels are off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using file from killer website itself:

http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux/20-killer-wireless-ac-in-linux-ubuntu-debian

And follow "Steps to install ath10k Driver:"

Reboot.

My wifi works now.

Thank you for all help.

Comment: Please don't answer questions with links. The link is now dead so your answer is useless. Next time, copy the relevant sections of the link directly into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You lack the needed firmware file to enable your card and driver to work properly. Please download this file on another computer and transfer it to the Ubuntu computer on a USB key or similar: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.157_all.deb

Drag and drop it to the desktop of the Ubuntu computer. Install it from the terminal with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot. Your wireless should be working. If not, please show us:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

It appears that the firmware you installed is ineffective. Please try:

```
sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/* 2> /dev/null
sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin?raw=true
sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin?raw=true
sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1?raw=true
```

Reboot. Your wireless should be working. If not, please show us:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1520343

Please try:

```
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/
mv board.bin  board.bin.bak
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Let's try a further step:

```
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/
mv board-2.bin  board.bin
```

Reboot and let us see:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Comment: Hi, the link is broken . It show popcorn.

Comment: Link corrected. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Hi, I can see enable wifi ticked now . But cant find wifi network. I update my question with result for that cmd. Thanks

Comment: I will have an edit in a few minutes.

Comment: I still cant find Wi-Fi Network. The output of dmesg | grep ath still same as above. Thanks

Comment: Another edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Hi I try it and keep show the same error . It cant find this 2 file ath10k/cal-pci-0000:04:00.0.bin and firmware-5.bin. Thanks

Comment: @CaalSaalVI Please edit the question to add the new dmesg results.  Not having those 2 files is normal

Comment: Please see a further edit in a few moments.